# How do I use a opensource Android project (no jar available) in my Eclipse Android project?

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, jar, gradle

Using Eclipse I've started an Android Project.

I wanted to create a FlowLayout but noticed that Android doesn't provide one in a native manner.

I've found two opensource projects in Github that provide a FlowLayout:

- https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout
- https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout

I want to use any of those in my project but they don't provide a compiled jar.
I'm trying to compile the code so I can get that jar and plug it into my project (in `/libs` and in the build path) but I can't import them as projects in Eclipse.

Question is:

### **How do I get/build the jars of any of those projects?**

If the answer is *"with gradle"* or *"with maven"*, can you guide me a little bit more? like:
*"Install maven, run cmd, run this, run that, **go and find the jar at ...**"*

When I've used third party code in my projects in the past I've always found the jars, eg:

- android-async-http-1.4.4.jar
- ocpsoft-pretty-time-1.0.7.jar
- joda-time-2.4.jar
- android-support-v7-appcompat.jar

So a second question is:
Is it a bad practice when open source projects don't provide a jar?

Comment: No, is not a duplicate, because here THERE IS NO JAR. Read the question before trying to close it.

Answer (score -1):

If it is a library project, here's what to do:

1. Import the library project into your workspace
2. Right click on **your** project, go to `Properties`
3. Click on `Android`
4. At the bottom, there is a `Library` section for you to add libraries. Click `Add`.
5. Select your library project, click `OK`
6. Done!

[Source: Referencing a library project](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject)

Comment: when I import to eclipse the "library project" and then add it as library to my project, I see that a jar is generated, but when I expand that jar I don't see the classes... just a META-INF